# How to convert the following output into a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

New to data science. I am using the following code to print the number of times 'i' happens in any column:

```
for i in np.arange(1,11):
  print(df[df['X']==i]['X'].value_counts())
```

The output I am getting is:

```
1 4
Name:X, dtype:int64
2 3
Name:X, dtype:int64
.
.
.
```

Is this a list or an array? How to check/know this?
and how to convert this whole output into a dataframe?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be the pandas way:

```
df['X'].eq(i).sum()
```

compare on the whole dataframe to `i`, then `sum` the booleans to count them (True == 1)

The output is a Series. you can convert to DataFrame if needed with `.to_frame()`